# Handling multiple modelattributes of same type in the same controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

i have following scenario :

```
@ModelAttribute("persons")
        public void addAttributes(Model model) {
         Person person = new Person()
         ;
         person.setAge(26);
         person.setFirstName("mars");
           model.addAttribute("persons", person);
        }

    @RequestMapping(value="/process-person")
    public ModelAndView processPerson(@ModelAttribute Person person,@ModelAttribute ("persons")Person persons,ModelAndView modelAndView ) {
        //
        //ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("person-result-page");
        modelAndView.getModel().remove("personObj");
        modelAndView.addObject("pers", person);
    ---->   modelAndView.addObject("pers2", persons);// persons holds the myname1 provided in input box
        modelAndView.addObject("personObj", person);

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

As shown in the -->  i want this variable -persons  to hold the value obtained from addAttributes() method but it is taking the same values that i input from the jsp page :

```
  <form:form method="POST" commandName="person-entity" action="process-person.html">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstName">Name:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
<br/>
```

i saw few similar questions but none of them resolved this problem . Here i want  values from addAttribute method to placed inside "persons" object, but it is taking the same value as that of "person" being provided from the form.jsp.

please help me out

Comment: When do you encounter this issue? I assume when you push the submit button? Or do you get in trouble when you just perform a GET request to /process-person?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467510/spring-framework-multiple-modelattributes-of-same-type?

Comment: i face this issue while clicking a hyperlink that directs me to the "/process-person" url .

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue. But when I HTTP GET to /process-person then `@ModelAttribute Person person` and `@ModelAttribute ("persons")Person persons` are totally different instances. The latter coming from your @ModelAttribute method, so I still don't got where your problem lies.

Comment: that is exactly what i was expecting ,.. two different instances but i got the same instances in the two argument parameters .

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem, when entering `processPerson` method on POST request triggered from your submit button from JSP. But this is the way, Spring handles the request. If you want two different instances, introduce a wrapper class to encapsulate the two person instances.

Comment: you mean i have to provide two different pojo classes for person? also can u plz share me the code that got this resolved via get .i am using a hyperlink to processPerson method

Comment: I've just copied your code, creating Person entity with age and firstName properties. No not two different classes. I mean, what is the context of your two persons? Are they in different roles for example? You should introduce a class containing two `Person` members anyway